# Range slider for y axis to avoid overlap in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm working on a project for creating a dash app. I have a problem with a horizontal barplot, in which I have a list of strings in the y axis and the frequency (taken from a database) on the x axis. The problem is that, if the list is too long, the graph appears like this:
[image]

Is there a way to show the first elements of the list on the y axis (to avoid the overlap) and scroll the y axis in order to see all the values more clearly or add a rangeslider for y axis? I'd like to maintain the bar chart horizontally. Here is my code for creating the figure:

```
trace1 = go.Bar(y=journals, x=journals_frequency,orientation='h', name='Number of journals')
layout1=go.Layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat=',d'),yaxis=dict(type='category',tickmode='linear'))
fig1=go.Figure(data=[trace1],layout=layout1)
```

Then I add the graph in my Dash app with "dcc.Graph(figure=fig1)".

Is there also a way to have a fixed weight for the figure even if the single string of the journal is too long?

Comment: Did you mean to say fixed width? Or what do you mean by weight of a figure?

Comment: Yes it's width, sorry! Because the width changes according to the length of the string. And I want the figure not to change, but maybe to put ellipses to long strings

Comment: Could you add the `journals` as text to the question?

Comment: "journals" is a column of a database, that can vary. According to the database I select, the length of the database can change. If the length is smaller than 20 (more or less) the graph is displayed correctly. But if the length higher (like in the image), I have all values overlapped. I want a graph in which I can scroll all the possible values in the y axis if they are too much.